# Insert STYLEs into TWebBrowser

Tags: html, delphi, twebbrowser, innertext

I am using TWebBrowser as editor GUI for users.  I want to be able to insert web controls into the document.  A simple example would be a check box. (I can elaborate why if needed).  I have all this working when I first assemble the HTML document (with its STYLE and SCRIPTS sections) and then pass it en-block to the TWebBrowser.  But now I want to be able to insert my elements into an existing document.

I have this code, below, but it is causing and OLE error (see in comments in code):

```
procedure THTMLTemplateDocument.EnsureStylesInWebDOM;
var StyleBlock : IHTMLElement;
    StyleText: string;
begin
  StyleBlock := FWebBrowser.GetDocStyle;
  if not assigned(StyleBlock) then
    raise Exception.Create('Unable to access <STYLE> block in web document');
  StyleText := FCumulativeStyleCodes.Text;
  StyleBlock.InnerText := StyleText; <--- generates "OLE ERROR 800A0258"
end;
```

The called functions from the above code are as follows:

```
function THtmlObj.GetDocStyle: IHTMLElement;
//Return pointer to <STYLE> block, creating this if it was not already present.
var
  Document:    IHTMLDocument2;         // IHTMLDocument2 interface of Doc
  Elements:    IHTMLElementCollection; // all tags in document body
  AElement:    IHTMLElement;           // a tag in document body
  Style, Head: IHTMLElement;
  I:           Integer;                // loops thru Elements in document body
begin
  Result := nil;
  if not Supports(Doc, IHTMLDocument2, Document) then
    raise Exception.Create('Invalid HTML document');
  Elements := Document.all;
  for I := 0 to Pred(Elements.length) do begin
    AElement := Elements.item(I, EmptyParam) as IHTMLElement;
    if UpperCase(AElement.tagName) <> 'STYLE' then continue;
    result := AElement;
    break;
  end;
  if not assigned(Result) then begin
    Head := GetDocHead;
    if assigned(Head) then begin
      Style := Document.CreateElement('STYLE');
      (Head as IHTMLDOMNode).AppendChild(Style as IHTMLDOMNode);
      Result := Style;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

and

```
function THtmlObj.GetDocHead: IHTMLElement;
//Return pointer to <HEAD> block, creating this if it was not already present.
var
  Document:    IHTMLDocument2;         // IHTMLDocument2 interface of Doc
  Elements:    IHTMLElementCollection; // all tags in document body
  AElement:    IHTMLElement;           // a tag in document body
  Body:        IHTMLElement2;          // document body element
  Head:        IHTMLElement;
  I:           Integer;                // loops thru Elements in document body
begin
  Result := nil;
  if not Supports(Doc, IHTMLDocument2, Document) then
    raise Exception.Create('Invalid HTML document');
  if not Supports(Document.body, IHTMLElement2, Body) then
    raise Exception.Create('Can''t find <body> element');
  Elements := Document.all;
  for I := 0 to Pred(Elements.length) do begin
    AElement := Elements.item(I, EmptyParam) as IHTMLElement;
    if UpperCase(AElement.tagName) <> 'HEAD' then continue;
    Result := AElement;
    break;
  end;
  if not assigned(Result) then begin
    Head := Document.CreateElement('HEAD');
    (Body as IHTMLDOMNode).insertBefore(Head as IHTMLDOMNode, Body as IHTMLDOMNode);
    //now look for it again
    Elements := Document.all;
    for I := 0 to Pred(Elements.length) do begin
      AElement := Elements.item(I, EmptyParam) as IHTMLElement;
      if UpperCase(AElement.tagName) <> 'HEAD' then continue;
      Result := AElement;
      break;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

When I run this, StyleText =

'.selected {'#$D#$A'  font-weight : bold;'#$D#$A'  //background-color : yellow;'#$D#$A'}'#$D#$A'.unselected {'#$D#$A'  font-weight : normal;'#$D#$A'  //background-color : white;'#$D#$A'}'#$D#$A#$D#$A

But I tried making StyleText to be something simple like 'hello', and it still crashed.

A Google search for "OLE ERROR 800A0258" reveals several other people who have had similar problems, such as [here](http://www.devsuperpage.com/search/Articles.asp?ArtID=99602) and [here](http://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/21663557/Changing-an-Elements-innerHTML-in-TWebBrowser.html) -- this later user seems to indicate he fixed the problem by using .OuterHTML, but I tried this with similar error generated.   [This](https://groups.yahoo.com/neo/groups/delphi-webbrowser/conversations/topics/5749) thread seems to indicate the .InnerText is read only.  But in the interface declaration (see below), it seems to have a method for setting (i.e. not read-only).

```
// *********************************************************************//
// Interface: IHTMLElement
// Flags:     (4416) Dual OleAutomation Dispatchable
// GUID:      {3050F1FF-98B5-11CF-BB82-00AA00BDCE0B}
// *********************************************************************//
  IHTMLElement = interface(IDispatch)
    ['{3050F1FF-98B5-11CF-BB82-00AA00BDCE0B}']
...
    procedure Set_innerHTML(const p: WideString); safecall;
    function Get_innerHTML: WideString; safecall;
    procedure Set_innerText(const p: WideString); safecall;
    function Get_innerText: WideString; safecall;
    procedure Set_outerHTML(const p: WideString); safecall;
    function Get_outerHTML: WideString; safecall;
    procedure Set_outerText(const p: WideString); safecall;
    function Get_outerText: WideString; safecall;
...
    property innerHTML: WideString read Get_innerHTML write Set_innerHTML;
    property innerText: WideString read Get_innerText write Set_innerText;
    property outerHTML: WideString read Get_outerHTML write Set_outerHTML;
    property outerText: WideString read Get_outerText write Set_outerText;
...
  end;
```

Can anyone help be figure out how to set up STYLES in the `<STYLE>` section of an existing HTML document in a TWebBrowser?

Comment: I had a delphi expert try to help me use the chromium embedded.  He told me that it worked great if the browser was on the main form.  But when it was on secondary forms, it wouldn't work right.

Comment: R.e. why not do it in Javascript ... I have a Delphi app, and I want to insert a template into the edit area (the TWebBrowser).  Currently there is a template engine that pops up a box, displays the template, and when done collapses to text which is inserted into the document.  I am trying to embed that template directly into the edit area.  The HTML document doesn't know what will be needed during the insertion, I don't think Javascript could do it.

Comment: Then you don't understand javascript. Spend a little time with it.  You can insert any object into the DOM, and manage those objects, their visibility, and location, via JavaScript. You can have that javascript request and load pieces of html at runtime and have it insert it into your page.   Check out jQuery.   If you want the user to be able to interact with the resulting HTML, you'll need some javascript knowledge anyways.  Eventually I think you will hit a wall unless you learn how to do this inside the javascript blocks executing inside a parent document.

Comment: @WarrenP Thanks for your post.  I am aware that javascript can manipulate the DOM.  But I think my setup is different than you are thinking.  This browser does not interact with the internet.  It only renders content passed to it by the Delphi app.  If javascript was to manipulate the DOM, then the Delphi code would have to first set up the javascript code and pass it in.  The chain of events originates with the Delphi code.   So I can set STYLES directly, or create javascript to do it.   Both actions initiate from Delphi code.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend that it interact with the internet. But it should interact with a local server that you are running, and I think having JavaScript+JQUERY-like-layer+load-from-page is better than reaching into the IShellDocView/IHTMLStyleSheet interfaces (designed in 1995) and trying to do everything that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have valid IHTMLDocument2, then you can call its [createStyleSheet()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms531194%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). It will return IHTMLStyleSheet instance. You can use its `cssText` property to set style.

Make sure you take account of document's character encoding.

Comment: This seems to be just what I was looking for.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Based on guidance from @Zamrony P. Juhara, I came up with the following code.  I am posting in case it can help anyone else in the future.

```
procedure THtmlObj.AddStylesToExistingStyleSheet(StyleSheet: IHTMLStyleSheet; SelectorSL, CSSLineSL : TStringList);
//NOTE: There must be a 1:1 correlation between SelectorSL and CSSLineSL
//  The first SL will contain the selector text
//  the second SL will contain all the CSS in one line (divided by ";"'s)
var
  SLIdx, RuleIdx, p: integer;
  SelectorText, CSSText, OneCSSEntry : string;
begin
  if not assigned(StyleSheet) then begin
    raise Exception.Create('Invalid StyleSheet');
  end;
  for SLIdx := 0 to SelectorSL.Count - 1 do begin
    SelectorText := SelectorSL.Strings[SLIdx];
    if SlIdx > (CSSLineSL.Count - 1) then break;
    CSSText := CSSLineSL.Strings[SLIdx];
    while CSSText <> '' do begin
      p := Pos(';', CSSText);
      if p > 0 then begin
        OneCSSEntry := MidStr(CSSText, 1, p);
        CSSText := MidStr(CSSText, p+1, Length(CSSText));
      end else begin
        OneCSSEntry := CSSText;
        CSSText := '';
      end;
      RuleIdx := StyleSheet.Rules.length;
      StyleSheet.addRule(SelectorText, OneCSSEntry, RuleIdx);
    end;
  end;
end;


function THtmlObj.AddStyles(SelectorSL, CSSLineSL : TStringList) :     IHTMLStyleSheet;
//NOTE: There must be a 1:1 correlation between SelectorSL and CSSLineSL
//  The first SL will contain the selector text
//  the second SL will contain all the CSS in one line (divided by ";"'s)
var
  Document:      IHTMLDocument2;              // IHTMLDocument2 interface of Doc
  StyleSheets:   IHTMLStyleSheetsCollection;  // document's style sheets
  StyleSheet:    IHTMLStyleSheet;             // reference to a style sheet
  OVStyleSheet:  OleVariant;                  // variant ref to style sheet
  Idx:           integer;
begin
  Result := nil;
  if not Supports(Doc, IHTMLDocument2, Document) then begin
    raise Exception.Create('Invalid HTML document');
  end;
  StyleSheets := Document.styleSheets;
  Idx := Document.StyleSheets.length;
  OVStyleSheet := Document.createStyleSheet('',Idx);
  if not VarSupports(OVStyleSheet, IHTMLStyleSheet, StyleSheet) then begin
    raise Exception.Create('Unable to create valid style sheet');
  end;
  Result := StyleSheet;
  AddStylesToExistingStyleSheet(StyleSheet, SelectorSL, CSSLineSL);
end; //AddStyles
```

Comment: Nice!  Sometimes I post things like this and even a year later I find my own code that way and use it again.